# Vote Early, Vote Often

Tags: discussion, votes

For me this is an absolutely necessary post to get a healthy status.

Jeff Atwood post an article about voting. Read: [Vote Early, Vote Often](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

Voting is the secong thing most important to SE sites. Don't waste your votes and incentive new user to vote.

Jeff also post an article about [Asking Better Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/). Please read and help us enforce the quality of questions.

- if you see a great, thoughtfully asked, well researched question, vote it up — please! Great questions are an art!
- if you see an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended question that you feel was asked in bad faith … vote it down.
- anything in between that’s salvageable, edit it — if you have the requisite 1,000 reputation.

Please **use your votes**.

Quoting RobertCartaino from chat:

> Vote, vote, vote. Encourage others to vote, vote, vote. On good content, leave signposts ("If you like this, please vote it up. It's important for the community!")-- in both meta and the main site. Maybe a few meta posts informing the users of the important of that type of participation. You are empowered a lot more than you know.

Comment: "Voting is the secong thing..." What...?

Comment: Sorry, what is the *question* again?

Comment: @Gan ~ The question is not really a question. @bigown is trying to remind people of the need to vote regularly on here, especially during the private beta.

Comment: bigown has a lot of experience with these sites, and he's seen it time and time again that some sites have not yet reached graduation simply because there is not enough voting for posts: [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Answer (score 7):

Bumping this to remind all our visitors to meta to vote, early and often ;)